# Issue with group by clause in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to use group by clause on one column but return the result set on how they are ordered in the table.For example if the table contains following data

```
"hutid"
45
23
45
22
56
13
56
13
```

Then I want the final result should be

```
45 -- 2
23 -- 1
22 -- 1
56 -- 2
13 -- 2
```

and my query is

```
$insert_query = "select hutids, count(*) as totalmail from hut group by hutids";
```

So it produces

```
13 -- 2    
22 -- 1
23 -- 1
45 -- 2
56 -- 2
```

I used order by rand but again it's not picking up the way ids are stored.Any hints will do great please.

Comment: Can you give the schema of the table?

Comment: How are you getting your `hutid` values out in the order shown in the first set of data? There is no intrinsic ordering of rows in relational database tables - without specifying a sort order, rows are likely to be retrieved in an essentially random order.

Comment: That's a 3rd party generated csv file which I am getting and then just dumping the data in hut table.

Comment: Just wondering if there is any possibility of using sub query?

Comment: Does the information imported from the CSV file include any other information apart from the `hutid` ?

Comment: no just a single field.

Comment: SQL tables represent unordered sets.  They have no ordering unless a column explicitly specifies the order.  You have not shown such a column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the order is maintained with this query

```
select @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS row_number, (SELECT @row_number:=0) AS t,hutid, count(*) as totalmail
from hut 
group by hutid
order by row_number
```

Comment: Simply brilliant,awesome. Thank you so much Rajesh. One question can you please explain this bit "@row_number:=0".

Comment: @Raj, it is a variable, that is incremented for each row as we fetch the values in select. we can also declare it above select instead of declaring it like what i did.